# C# use return value from class in function call

Tags: c#, function, call

I tried to figure it out but I don't get a clue on either how to pass a result of a new instance of a class to a function call or if this is even possible.

If I wan't to pass a random number, I'll have to create it first:

```
int n = 0;
Random rnd = New Random();
int m = rnd.Next(0, n);

MyClass.MyFunction(MyValue1, m);
```

Actually, this is 4 lines of code. However, as a newbie to c# I've already seen a lot and want to know, if there is a shorter version of this. Some pseudo code:

```
MyClass.MyFunction(MyValue1, Random rnd = new Random() {rnd.Next(0, n); return});
```

Is this somehow possible? I thought I have seen something like this but can't find anything about it.

Comment: You generally want a single `Random` object to pull random numbers from, so in this case you might want your `new Random` to be in a constructor or static property, then you only need to `rnd.Next` to get your next random number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `Next` just after `new Random()`

```
MyClass.MyFunction(MyValue1, new Random().Next(0,n));
```

`new Random()` will create object of `Random` and on it you can call `Next()`. So it's possible to call it inline without need to store `Random` before.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't expect it to be that easy :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll simply leave this here

```
MyClass.MyFunction(MyValue1, ((Func<int>)(() =>
{
    int n = 0;
    var rnd = new Random();
    return rnd.Next(0, n);
}))());
```

P.S.: it compiles and works.

As @crashmstr commented, it's actually not a good idea specifically to `Random`. For single random value is ok, but for series of random numbers you don't want to create new instance every time or your numbers will become [not so random](https://stackoverflow.com/q/767999/1997232).